# Very strange 'Unparseable date' issue in android 2.3.4 (not in 2.2)

Tags: android, android-activity, simpledateformat

I have an application, which was running perfectly on emulator 2.2 and real device 2.2.2. I decided to update my android version on phone from 2.2.2 do 2.3.4. Everything went fine, but my application suddenly stopped working without any reason. Well, it gets me `Unparseable date` exception on this line:

```
String timeOld12Hour = "11:50pm";// for example
Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma").parse(timeOld12Hour);
```

Thats really funny, because i can't see any error on this line. SImpledateformatter is exactly same format as my date. Whats most strange:

- it works fine emulator 2.2
- it works fine emulator 2.3.3
- it works fine every pc with java i tried today
- it worked fine on device 2.2.2
- it doesnt work on device 2.3.4

Where can be problem? I tried few phone restarts, uninstall application, reinstall application, i simple can't get it working...

Comment: Which devices does this not work on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i found what was the problem. If add `Locale.US` to `SimpleDateFormatconstructor`, like this:

```
String timeOld12Hour = "11:50pm";// for example
Date time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma", Locale.US).parse(timeOld12Hour);
```

everything goes fine. Thats really funny, I have never heard about something like this ;) I must read something more about locales, because it looks its very important. Also still can't understand why locale of my phone changed after Android upgrade...

Comment: I have a valid date that throws this exception (even when using Local.US) on android 2.3.3, but works fine on newer versions. Did you understand the root cause?